# Hash Table: adding and finding functions

Tags: c, memory-management, hash-map

I made this function to teach myself about hash tables. Any ideas? I commented out `free(addition)` because it was giving me a compiler error, but I need to figure out how to deallocate the memory.

```
#define hashSize 1000

typedef struct hashElem{
    char* date;
    char* holiday;
}hashElem;

typedef struct hash{
    struct hashElem element;
    struct hash* next;
}hash;

hash* hashTable[hashSize];

// Hash function
size_t murmurHash(const void *keyPtr, size_t keySize)
{
     /*  DESCRIPTION:    Very fast string hashing algorithm with excelleng distribution and 
     *                  collision resistance. This source code has been released into the public
     *                  domain.
     *
     *  NOTES:          http://murmurhash.googlepages.com
     *
     *  RETURNS:        Hashtable index for the key
     *
     */

    /* 'm' and 'r' are mixing constants generated offline.         */
    /* They're not really 'magic', they just happen to work well.  */

    const unsigned int m = 0x5bd1e995;
    const int r = 24;

    size_t hashValue = 0;

    /* Mix 4 bytes at a time into the hash */

    const unsigned char * data = (const unsigned char *)keyPtr;

    while(keySize >= 4)
    {
        unsigned int k = *(unsigned int *) data;

        k *= m; 
        k ^= k >> r; 
        k *= m; 

        hashValue *= m; 
        hashValue ^= k;

        data += 4;
        keySize -= 4;
    }

    /* Handle the last few bytes of the input array */

    switch(keySize)
    {
        case 3: hashValue ^= data[2] << 16;
        case 2: hashValue ^= data[1] << 8;
        case 1: hashValue ^= data[0];
                hashValue *= m;
    }; 

    /* Do a few final mixes of the hash to ensure the last few  */
    /* bytes are well-incorporated.                             */

    hashValue ^= hashValue >> 13;
    hashValue *= m;
    hashValue ^= hashValue >> 15;

    return (hashValue % hashSize);
}

// strlen: return length of string
int strlen(char *s)
{
    char* p = s;

    while (*p != '\0')
        ++p;
    return p - s;
}

// Add Holiday into hash table
void addHoliday(char* date, char* holiday)
{
   char* key;
   int keyLen;
   size_t keyHash;
   hash* addition = malloc(sizeof(*addition));

   key = date;
   addition->element.date = key;
   addition->element.holiday = holiday;

   // Add holiday to Hash Table
   if (hashTable[murmurHash(key, strlen(key))] == NULL)
   {    
       addition->next = NULL;
       hashTable[murmurHash(key, strlen(key))] = addition; 
   }
   else  //If there is already an element at the index, add current holiday to beginning of list
   {
       addition->next = hashTable[murmurHash(key, strlen(key))];
       hashTable[murmurHash(key, strlen(key))] = addition;
   }

   //free(addition);
}

// If a date is entered, retrieve holiday from hash function index
char* getHoliday(char* date)
{
    return(hashTable[murmurHash(date, strlen(date))]->element.holiday);
}

void main(void)
{
   addHoliday("01/01/13", "New Years Day");
   printf("%s\n", getHoliday("01/01/13"));

   getchar();
}
```

Comment: Is the question how to deallocate memory?

Comment: the question is for an overall code review along with some comments about any area where memory is being leaked

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working C code dealing with lists: problem with memory leak](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30087/working-c-code-dealing-with-lists-problem-with-memory-leak)

Answer (score 6):

For one thing, this:

```
   // Add holiday to Hash Table
   if (hashTable[murmurHash(key, strlen(key))] == NULL)
   {    
       addition->next = NULL;
       hashTable[murmurHash(key, strlen(key))] = addition; 
   }
   else  //If there is already an element at the index, add current holiday to beginning of list
   {
       addition->next = hashTable[murmurHash(key, strlen(key))];
       hashTable[murmurHash(key, strlen(key))] = addition;
   }
```

can simply be this:

```
   // Add holiday to Hash Table
   size_t idx = = murmurHash(key, strlen(key));
   addition->next = hashTable[idx];
   hashTable[idx] = addition;
```

Which cuts at least one invoke of the hash function, and in the process a similar number of `strlen` invokes. There is little sense is "checking" for a NULL in the hash table slot, because that is precisely what you want the `next` pointer of your new node to be anyway.

Not entirely clear either is whether you intended on your keys being **unique**. Both code snippets above (yours and mine) do *not* enforce unique keys. It is worth a thought to determine whether that feature is needed or not.

And (not really) finally, try and make a habit of creating hash functions that are *independent* of the hash table size. Though that may sound odd, it makes sense from the perspective of reuse. A hash function ideally returns a "value". That value is then massaged (usually via a modulo with the hash table size) to drive the final key into a slot within the table constraints. But that operation is *separate* from the hash function itself, which should be restricted only by the domain of the return type. In other words, this:

```
size_t murmurHash(const void *key, size_t len)
```

should simply return a value between 0 and the maximum value of a `size_t` on the platform. Period. No table size should be involved in the has function itself. Just chew on data and return some `size_t`. The *caller* of the function (the inserter, the lookup, etc), then takes this value and restricts it down to the table size (usually via a modulo of some kind). This makes the invocation look something like this:

```
   // Add holiday to Hash Table
   size_t idx = = murmurHash(key, strlen(key)) % hashSize;
   addition->next = hashTable[idx];
   hashTable[idx] = addition;
```

Though it may seem a little odd at first, it makes your hash functions *more robust*. They are not restricted by some table size. The *user* of the hash function does that step; not the function itself. This is the approach used by the standard C++ library `std::hash<>` template, and it is a good design to emulate.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with WhozCraig; it is not necessary to run the hash multiple times.  I would add that freeing the pointer (`addition`) would result in loss of the data you just added.  Your array `hashTable` is an array of pointers - it doesn't include storage for the `hash` elements themselves.  Thus, you can't free any `hash` elements until you remove them from the table or are done with the table itself.

Tearing down the table will have to go something like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < hashSize ; i++) {
    hash* ptrToFree = hashTable[i];
    while (ptrToFree != NULL) {
        hash* next = ptrToFree->next;
        mfree(ptrToFree);
        ptrToFree = next;
    }
}
```

If you don't like iterating over all of your pointers (it *looks* time-consuming, but you're probably on the way out of your process, right?) you can keep a static list of all elements, then iterate through that.

```
typedef struct _HashStorage {
    struct hash element;
    struct _HashStorage * more;
} HashStorage;

HashStorage* storage = NULL;

hash* newHash() {
    HashStorage* oldTop = storage;
    storage = malloc(sizeof(HashStorage));
    storage->more = oldTop;
    return (hash*) storage;
}

void dispose() {
    HashStorage* iterator = storage;
    while (iterator != NULL) {
        HashStorage* more = iterator->more;
        mfree(iterator);
        iterator = more;
    }
}
```